# Trouble using prepare and bind_param in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble using prepare and bind_param statements in php. My code is as follows:

```
<?php


$dbhost = 'localhost'; //default
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = ‘somepassword’;
//Create a connection object
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if($conn->connect_error )
{
  die('Could not connect: %s' . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully<br>";

$conn->select_db("TUTORIAL");

$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tutorial_info (tutorial_title,tutorial_author) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$tutorial_title,$tutorial_author);

//try and insert
$tutorial_title=“English Lit”;
$tutorial_author=“Bob Trotter”;
$stmt->execute();





//Close the database
$conn->close();




 ?>
```

When I execute the script I get the message "connected successfully" however if I check the table contents the new row has not been added. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

I also see in the documentation that in bind_param we add an additional parameter i.e $stmt->bind_param(**"sss"**,$tutorial_title,$tutorial_author); In this case it is "sss". What is it used for? Can I get rid of it?

Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `bind_param` describes the types of the parameters. [RTM!](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

You can specify `s` for `string` and `i` for `integer` for example. The number of characters in the first parameters have to cover the number of the other parameters exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php


$dbhost = 'localhost'; //default
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = ‘somepassword’;
//Create a connection object
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if($conn->connect_error )
{
  die('Could not connect: %s' . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully<br>";

$conn->select_db("TUTORIAL");

$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tutorial_info (tutorial_title,tutorial_author) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$tutorial_title,$tutorial_author);

//try and insert
$tutorial_title=“English Lit”;
$tutorial_author=“Bob Trotter”;
$stmt->execute();





//Close the database
$conn->close();




 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra s

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tutorial_info (tutorial_title,tutorial_author) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$tutorial_title,$tutorial_author);
```